# woocommerce-how can i get all products by their groups!

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

i have a wordpress site that uses woocommerce as an online shop plugin. what is want is listing all products in my woocommerce site grouped by their categories, how can i do this? i want the list sorted ASC and i want all empty categories hidden!
thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this is what you need:

```
$args = array(
'orderby'    => 'name',
'hide_empty' => 1
);
$category_terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

foreach($category_terms as $cat_term){

echo $cat_term->name;
}
```

btw: woocommerce is offtopic here!